# Search for a string only in files less than a day old

Tags: batch-file, find

I'm trying to make a batch file to search for a string in files that start with a service and are from the past 24 hrs.

I am able to get it to search for the string in all the files starting with service in the folder but, I can't get it to only search for files that start with service from the past 24 hours. I tried `forfiles` and find together but they didnt work.

```
find "text to search for" ...\Logs\service* -mtime -1
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto fail
goto pass

:pass
do stuff
goto end

:fail
do stuff

:end
PAUSE
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use Linux `find`'s parameters on Winodws, it's not going to work. Would be easier if you could switch to PowerShell, is that an option?

Comment: Your sample code does not contain `forfiles` although you mentioned it... anyway, I think it is the wrong choice as the `/D` option with a positive (`+`) number like `/D +1` means current date plus one, so it matches only files that have been changed in the future (don't ask me what the developers thought of when programming that tool); so the best option is not to use pure batch scripting as date arithmetics is very painful there; perhaps *PowerShell*, *JavaScript* or *VBScript* were suitable alternatives (or also batch Hybrids)...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find the files first then grep for your text

Something like:

```
find ...\Logs\ -name service* -mtime -1 -exec grep 'text to search for' {} \;
```

Comment: It says "File not found - service*" , I created a dummy file with random text to test it and it does not catch it

Comment: I create events under the pass and fail sections. its weird cause then the command prompt says success and creates a passing event. Right now I have a file that should pass, and a file that should fail from the past day

Comment: Maybe try the absolute path to your directory instead of relative...I tested this    find /data1/log/cassandra/ -name system* -mtime -1 -exec grep 'ERROR \[' {} \;  on my system and it returned the correct results...